# How can I evaluate $\limsup_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SupremumLimit.html) page for supremum limits doesn't mention if or how $$\limsup_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$$ is implemented in Mathematica. Is there a way to evaluate expressions of this form? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Admittedly, MathWorld hasn't been updated too frequently. Nevertheless, 11.2 has the function [`MaxLimit[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxLimit.html), e.g. `MaxLimit[Sin[x] - 1/x, x -> Infinity]`.

Comment: Moreover, searching the documentation center for limsup gives MaxLimit as a hit.